# Canonical way to map SourceFile class attribute to actual file system path

Tags: jvm, javac, .class-file, jdi

The `SourceFile` attribute only contains the file name, not a full or relative path. This is not much information to go with because `javac` will place the `.class` file in a potentially unrelated directory (relative to the `-d` argument), based on the package in which the class is declared. While this is required for finding and loading the class at run time, it makes the `.class` file location only a hint to where the `.java` file might be located in the source tree.

The documentation of the 
[`com.sun.jdi.ReferenceType.sourcePaths(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/ReferenceType.html#sourcePaths(java.lang.String)) method suggests a heuristics to obtain a file system path:

> In the reference implementation, for strata which do not explicitly specify source path (the Java programming language stratum never does), the returned strings are the sourceNames(String) prefixed by the package name of this ReferenceType converted to a platform dependent path.

There is no obvious way to do better than that. Of course, if the file does not exist at the expected location, one could search the source tree and check if the file name happens to be unique, and use that as the location. But beyond that, there are not many options.

Are there any other, non-obvious ways to solve this?

Comment: The SourceFile attribute is meant for display in stack traces. It was never meant to handle what you're trying to do.

Comment: Interesting, I had not considered this. What are source-level debuggers supposed to do then?

Comment: In the case of an IDE, typically, it is using the IDE's own compiler and build system, so it knows exactly where each class file came from. You'd need to do something like that anyway to be able to support other common IDE features.

Comment: @Antimony not all code has been compiled by the IDE itself. Just think the JRE classes or 3rd party libraries. In case of Eclipse I can say for sure that it *does* use the `SourceFile` attribute (even for runtime generated classes) and applies some heuristic regarding where to search for the actual source file. It even works for source file whose syntax it doesn’t understand.